# How find function work in set and map for string data type in cpp

Tags: c++, stl

How find function searches the string in STL set.

See the below code snippet

```
#include<set>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string> myset{"Hello","Hi"};
    if(myset.find("Hello") != myset.end()){
        cout<<"Find"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<" Didn't find"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I am not sure how find() method work internally, how it checks the string? Does it use like strcmp function?

Comment: related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find

Answer (score 0):

No it uses the `<` operator. If `a<b` is false and `a>b` is also false then it must be that a equals b.

In fact `strcmp` cannot be used for `std::string` comparisons because `strcmp` treats the nul character (`'\0'`) as the end of a string, but `std::string` can contain nul characters.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set`, whether it contains `std::string` or not, uses a comparator to search the set. The default comparator is [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), which uses the `<` operator for comparison.

`"Hello"` gets implicitly converted to a `std::string`, so this results in the overloaded `<` operator comparing `std::string`s, to effect your`find()`. Because C++ `std::string` can contain `'\0'`, this cannot use the C library's `strcmp` function.

In C++14 and later one can override the comparator to the `std::less<void>` transparent overload. This results (via a sequence of events) of employing other `<` overloads that compare a `std::string` with a `const char *` directly, avoiding the need to construct a temporary `std::string` object solely for the purpose of doing the `find()`. In C++20, and going forward this is implemented using the `<=>` overload.

Unfortunately you have to explicitly specify the `std::less<void>` comparator, since the default `set` comparator [is still `std::less<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).